# VueJs + Webpack lazyload modules from ElementUI

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, lazy-loading

I would like to lazy-load a specific element of ElementUI in a Vue component.

I tried this:

```js
import { Tree } from /* webpackChunkName : "element-ui" */ 'element-ui';

Vue.component(Tree.name, Tree);
Vue.use(Tree);
```

And this:

```js
{
  components: {
    'el-tree': () => import(/* webpackChunkName : "element-ui" */ "element-ui").then(({Tree}) => Tree)
  }
}
```

But in both cases, the `element-ui.js` chunk file is not created, and the full library is inserted into the `main.js` file instead.

How do I dynamically import only the used elements of ElementUI (not the entire library)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Why does `import('element-ui').then(({Tree}) => Tree)` bundle the whole ElementUI library?

The `element-ui` [library is a CommonJS module](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/54eeb5c/build/webpack.common.js#L16), which is not tree-shakeable ([`webpack-common-shake`](https://github.com/indutny/webpack-common-shake) exists, but your mileage may vary).

> Can I import only individual elements from ElementUI?

The ElementUI [docs](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart#on-demand) recommend using [`babel-plugin-component`](https://github.com/ElementUI/babel-plugin-component) (also written by ElementUI) to import only the elements used. The usage is documented as follows:

1. Install `babel-plugin-component`:

   ```
   npm install babel-plugin-component -D
   ```
2. Edit `.babelrc` to include:

   ```js
   {
     "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }]],
     "plugins": [
       [
         "component",
         {
           "libraryName": "element-ui",
           "styleLibraryName": "theme-chalk"
         }
       ]
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Statically import the desired element, and initialize it as a Vue component:

   ```js
   import { Button } from 'element-ui';
   Vue.component(Button.name, Button);
   ```

> Can I dynamically import individual elements?

Yes, it's possible.

First, it's useful to understand how `babel-plugin-component` works. The plugin effectively converts this:

```js
import { __ComponentName__ } from 'element-ui';
Vue.component('x-foo', __ComponentName__);
```

into:

```js
import __ComponentName__ from 'element-ui/lib/__component-name__';
import 'element-ui/lib/__styleLibraryName__/__component-name__.css';
Vue.component('x-foo', __ComponentName__);
```

*Notes:*

- `__styleLibraryName__` is configured in the Babel preset options within `.babelrc`.
- The conversion includes formatting the component's name (`__ComponentName__`) in kebab-case (`__component-name__`). For example, `Button` becomes `button`; and `DatePicker` becomes `date-picker`.
- Make sure to remove existing ElementUI imports, which would defeat the "on demand" imports:

  ```js
  // import ElementUI from 'element-ui'; // REMOVE
  // import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'; // REMOVE
  ```

So, we can use that knowledge to dynamically import a specific element like this:

```js
// main.js
import 'element-ui/lib/__styleLibraryName__/__component-name__.css';
Vue.component('x-foo', () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "x-foo" */ 'element-ui/lib/__component-name__'));
```

Or:

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<script>
import 'element-ui/lib/__styleLibraryName__/__component-name__.css';

export default {
  components: {
    'x-foo': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "x-foo" */ 'element-ui/lib/__component-name__'),
  }
}
</script>
```

For example, to import `Button` with the Chalk theme:

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<script>
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/button.css';

export default {
  components: {
    'el-button': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "element-button" */ 'element-ui/lib/button'),
  }
}
</script>
```

However, these elements are relatively small and thus probably not worth lazy-loading, considering the overhead of the network requests for the container chunk plus the element chunk. On the other hand, the savings might be worthwhile if the elements were conditionally rendered and that condition were rarely true.

Comment: Holy crap this answer was so helpful.