# how to import components on demand for reduced file size [Element-UI]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

So I want to use a couple of components from the Element-UI library. I noticed on their website that I can import components on demand to make the project smaller ([see here](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart)). The problem is that when I import components on demand, the size of the project doesn't get any smaller.

An example:

The following two uses and imports of the Element-UI library give me the ***exact same*** file size when running `npm run build`

*Import 1:*

```
//full import
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

Vue.use(ElementUI);
```

*Import 2:*

```
//on demand
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/button.css';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/collapse.css';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/popover.css';

import { Button } from 'element-ui';
import { Popover } from 'element-ui';
import CollapseTransition from 'element-ui/lib/transitions/collapse-transition';

Vue.use(Button)
Vue.use(Popover)
Vue.component(CollapseTransition.name, CollapseTransition)
```

The library is quite large, so even though my project is rather small, when running `npm run build`, Vue is already giving me the following warning:
`entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.`

Comment: Do you analyze the size of the module through the `bundleAnalyzerReport`?

Comment: No I did not, I don't even know what it is hehe. After `npm run build` Vue logs the size of the different files in `KiB`. I just look at that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104217/vuejs-webpack-lazyload-modules-from-elementui

Comment: Thank you very much Jay. I'll look into it :)