# Why is element-ui importing the entire library? | Large bundle size

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, element-ui

So, I am trying to import a few components from `Element-ui` on demand, but for some reason it keeps importing the entire library ([docs about importing on demand here)](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart#on-demand). See image below.

[image]

I already followed this post on [how to import individual elements from ElementUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104217/vuejs-webpack-lazyload-modules-from-elementui).

I installed the `element-ui` library with npm.

Then in my `main.js` file I import components on demand as follows:

```
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/button.css';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/popover.css';

import { Button } from 'element-ui';
import { Popover } from 'element-ui';

Vue.use(Button)
Vue.use(Popover)
```

I installed the `babel-plugin-component` dependency. It uses the following config in `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "es2015",
            {
                "modules": false
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "component",
            {
                "libraryName": "element-ui",
                "styleLibraryName": "theme-chalk"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I also use the [Message](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/message#local-import) function quite a lot. I used to import this in every component I use the function like they have stated in their documentation:

`import { Message } from 'element-ui';`

But I've read somewhere that that also imports the entire lib. So I changed that to this:

`import Message from 'element-ui/packages/message';`

But whatever I do, my bundle (and specifically ElementUI) keeps getting bigger...

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you also share your reproducible repo?

Comment: Well. I was building a reproducible repo and figured out that babel wasn't configured properly in my main project and that that was the reason it was acting so strange. So in a way, you solved the mystery :).

Comment: @reinier68, can you share what the issue/babel setting you had to update was?

Comment: @Mark I can't remember. I've looked at the project and the only thing I am doing is importing in `main.js` like this: `import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/popover.css';` and then `import { popover } from 'element-ui'`. Lastly: `Vue.use(Popover);`. And I have created a `babel.config.js` file that just has the default preset: ` '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'` and that's it as far as I can tell.

Comment: same as config as you metioned. still 900k(gzip 200k)...